# Is there anyway to see the full attribute name in interface builder?

Tags: xcode

[image: Is there anyway to see the full attribute name because I can't seem to see it past the ...]

Take a look at the picture and see what I mean:

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report with Apple. In the meantime, until Apple fixes this (if ever), use shorter names, or at least move the distinguishing feature to an earlier part of the name!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long attribute name:

[image]

If I hover the mouse over the name, a "tooltip" appears showing the full name:

[image]

That is what you'll have to do. Or use shorter names.